# XGBoost Original Paper Notation for Loss Function

Tags: boosting, cart, loss-functions

I'm working through the original XGBoost paper by [Chen & Guestrin](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754.pdf) (2016) and I noticed they dropped a subscript *i* for y-hat between the first loss function and the second order approximation version...

From:
[image]

To: [image]

Does this dropping of the subscript have any meaning? I'm having a hard time figuring it out.

Comment: You have sharp eyes, but the article you’re citing is the preprint — basically, a draft from before the final editing and not the eventual publication. My surmise is that this is merely a typo.

Comment: Kindest thanks! I appreciate your insight since I'm still conditioning my judgement skills. Interestingly, I found Chen's dissertation as published 3 years later and the typo (keeping with your surmise) was there as well on pg 10: https://digital.lib.washington.edu/researchworks/handle/1773/44766